# Convincing Nuget that I've met a dependency from another package

Tags: nuget

I have a project where I'd like to use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bootstrap.Datepicker/, so being a good modern developer I tell VS to add that nuget package.  Which is cool.  But along with it comes Bootstrap 2.3.1, which I know is a dependency of that package.  But my project already has the Bootstrap Less Source (3.2.0.1) package installed, and I'm concerned about having two different "instances" of the "same" package in my project.  Another developer on my team has pointed out that any and all Nuget packages that are based on bootstrap probably will require the default one, not the less source package we're using, even though that works best for us.

Is there some way in nuget to tell it to ignore dependencies, or convince it that instead of the dependency it's expecting, it's been met in another way?